# Java Naming Convention between different layer classes

Tags: java, naming-conventions

How would you guys elegantly name/baptize these classes, assuming prefix/sulfix like I, Impl, Dao, etc, are bad conventions!

I know it is possible to find many topics about naming convensions, but they are more about it than suggesting on how to handle those cases.

The ideia is to decouple any possible implementation between layers/modules and let the container to handle injections.

- **model**: Company
- **company service interface**: ICompanyService
- **service implementation class**: CompanyService implements ICompanyService
- **persistence interface**: ICompanyDao
- **persistence implementation class**: CompanyDao implements ICompanyDao

I can't get rid of "I" at interface names cause interface and implementations would be named as the same (I know it is possible to use full name including package, but it is even uglier). Same case for CompanyDao. Also the same issue when DAO sulfix is removed because of model class name.

Comment: I have `DescriptiveCompanyService implements CompanyService` If you only have one implementation perhaps you don't need an interface then it's just `CompanyService`

Comment: Package by feature, not layer - http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=205 https://dzone.com/articles/project-package-organization

Comment: @PeterLawrey - yes, it would work for my Service classes indeed! How about DAO ones. Which naming would you put on Dao classes and its Interface?

Comment: @user3592331 - How changing to package feature would solve the naming convention question and keep things decoupled???